# Generating a random background color every second?

Tags: javascript

```
var color = function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

var bgcolor = document.body.style.backgroundColor;

setInterval(function() { 
     bgcolor = color;
}, 1000);
```

The color variable is used to generate a random color, bgcolor variable got the body's bg color inside of it, and I set the interval for 1 second each. Is that okay? There seem to have a problem but I can't figure it out, maybe I need to put the color var INSIDE the set interval to generate it each second? If so, what's the easiest way to do so?
Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

You initially assign `bgColor` the value of the body background - this is just a value, `bgColor` is *not a reference* to the bodys background color - you'd have to set that each time in the interval.

```
setInterval(function() { 
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color(); //() to execute the function!
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You could put the `document.body.style` object in a variable though outside of the interval.

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you! :) I hate myself for never being able to continue writing a code till the end, I always stumble on things like that, small things but they make everything bug. I guess it comes with practice :D Thanks again!

Comment: @Bergi the difference is insignificant. I have tested it with 1M accesses, the difference is ~70ms (7%). That's nothing if you take in account that with this frequency, it would take 11.5 days, 70ms less doesn't change that much.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak: Of course there's no performance problem here. I'm just saying that only the `.backgroundColor` property assignment needs to go inside the function.

Comment: What is the point then, why would one want to cache a reference and only use it in the one place?